# Unable to extract JS Object data

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the color value from the variable 'colorArray' but it's showing undefined.

typeof(colorArray) is showing type as OBJECT.
This color array i got using flot getData as follows:

```
var colorArray=[];
var plot = $.plot(placeholder,dataset,options);
for(var i=0;i<plot.getData().length;i++) {
    var series = plot.getData()[i].color;
    colorArray.push(series);
}
```

[image: **chrome console output**]

Comment: Very less code is exposed. Would be happy to help you if the complete code is exposed.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are getting the color?

Comment: why series.color? use only series in push method

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but if plot.getData()[i].color is already a color value, than just change it to

```
var series = plot.getData()[i].color;
colorArray.push(series);
```

Comment: sorry, man .. that was my own mistake.. That's actually series only